# fatal error: 'mysql/mysql.h' file not found

Tags: mysql, c

I have installed mysql using

```
brew install mysql
```

Then compiled using

```
gcc -I/usr/include mydb.c
```

However it gives me the error:

```
fatal error: 'mysql/mysql.h' file not found
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am on macosx 10.12

edit: tried gcc -I/usr/local/include/mysql/ mydb.c still broken

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h`? What does `stat /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yeah, it doesn't exist. Any idea where homebrew installs libraries? Found it, its in /usr/local/include/mysql/ for me however gcc -I/usr/local/include/mysql/ mydb.c still gives the same error

Comment: You might check out the documentation for suggestions:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-building-clients.html

Comment: You can build *mysql* yourself, you just need cmake and all the dependencies, which have to be installed anyway if you will develop anything with *libmysqlclient*.

Comment: are you sure the install of mysql was successful?

Comment: I suspect what you installed in the mysql server.  What you actually need is the development package. *libmysqlclient* with the associated header files.     On linux the appropriate command would be: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`   I would expect something similar on the max os x system

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu16.04,mysql.h locates in /usr/include/mysql.
You can find it after install libmysqlclient20 or libmysqlclient-dev.

Answer (score 0):

Verify at where are install  mysql, for this, using the command for see the file list of directory

```
ls
```

and using

```
cd
```

The installation, in my example, are is in directory:

```
/usr/local/mysql-<version_my_mysql>/include/
```

second step is indicate the directory everytime compiller:

```
gcc my_program_code_file.c -I /usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/include/ -o my_program_executable
```

the includers in code are:

```
#include <mysql.h>
```